# below python3 pygeocoder module unable to execute as it causing Error OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: python-3.x

from pygeocoder import Geocoder
results = Geocoder.geocode("Tian'anmen, Beijing")

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygeocoder.py", line 129, in geocode
    return GeocoderResult(Geocoder.get_data(params=params))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygeocoder.py", line 212, in get_data
    raise GeocoderError(response_json['status'], response.url)
pygeolib.GeocoderError: Error OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
Query: https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=china&sensor=false&bounds=&region=&language=&components=